# Convert values from 2 colums into rows T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, excel, t-sql

I have a problem that i am not able to fix.

I have a table like this

[image: table1]

i want the output to be like this (NOT this, look at the revised result image):

[image: result]

is this possible with T-SQL? maybe with Excel?

There are 140 categories and approx. 60.000 rows.

Edit:

Just to clarify. I want an amount column for every category column. So if there are 140 categories, i want 140 amount columns. If there is no amount for a given category, it just going to null or amount =0.

EDIT2:
Revised result:
[image: revised]

Comment: Are you sure that this is what you want? This seems to be a pretty typical case for a simple pivot table where the categories are shown in separate columns. So, you'd have a column `cat1` with the value 132 and a column `cat2` with a value of 413, column `cat3` with a value of 1245, etc. But the picture of your expected outcome seems to differ from that and expects a separate "amount" column. What do you want to show in these columns?

Comment: Hi Ralph. I want an amount column for each category column. So if there are 140 categories, i want 140 amounts horizontally.

Comment: But you are showing one column for `cat2`. So, in that column I'd expect the value for `cat2`. Hence, a pivot table would show in the `cat2` column the value 132. But what do you want to show in the column `amount` next to `cat2`? Once again, please verify that you are not looking for a solution like this one instead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931607/convert-rows-to-columns-using-pivot-in-sql-server OR this https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Hi Ralph. I have revised my result. I made a mistake.

Comment: In this case you'll have to do it in Excel with VBA as this is **not** possible in T-SQL. This is due to the fact that all column names in T-SQL must be unique per table. This condition is not met with your specific requirements as you'll have **two** columns for each category: the first column will repeat the categories name and the second (adjacent) column will show the value for the given category. So, the columns `category` and `amount` will repeat as many times as there are categories in your table. Hence, you'll have to program a solution with VBA.

Comment: Ohh. Thanks for your help Ralph. I hoped it was possible.

Comment: What if the column names where like Category_cat1, Category_cat2 etc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143570/discussion-between-ralph-and-uba2012).

Comment: @Ralph the question doesn't say anything about creating a table of this structure. A select result can have duplicate column names.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pivot and dynamic query to generate into columns.. I just gave a sample with 2 categories you can generate the complete list using your table

```
select * from #yourcustomer
pivot (sum(amount) for category_name in ([cat1],[cat2] --,all categories list generated based on yourtable..........
)) p
```